# Algorithm to display number of views and comments

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have written something like this:

```
var _views = (@Model.Views == 1 ? "view" : "views");
var _comments = (@Model.Comments == 1 ? "comment" : "comments");

if(@Model.Views > 0)
{
   if (@Model.Comments > 0)
   {
       @String.Format("{0:n0} {1}, {2:n0} {3}", @Model.Views, _views, @Model.Comments, _comments);
   }
   else
   {
       @String.Format("{0:n0} {1}", @Model.Views, _views);
   }
}
else if (@Model.Comments > 0)
{
   @String.Format("{0:n0} {1}", @Model.Comments, _comments);
}
```

It actually works.

It displays number of views and comments a video has (e.g. http://www.voiceofconscience.org/Video/2 )

There was a singular/plural problem which I have solved in this low quality manner.

I was wondering how it supposed to look like to be considered as a "good style"

Greets
Mariusz

Comment: Thanks for correcting the format marc_s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would look better if you'd accumulate result string instead of running into if-else debris.
Smth like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
if(@Model.Views > 0)
  sb.AppendFormat("{0:n0} {1}",@Model.Views, _views);
if(@Model.Comments> 0)
  sb.AppendFormat("{0:n0} {1}",@Model.Comments, _comments);
```

Comment: This doesn't produce a comma between the counts.

Comment: Thanks Roger. Aasmund has similar but this seems smoother :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is somewhat more compact, and it generalizes to more than two counts:

```
var items = new List<string>();
if (Model.Views > 0)
    items.Add(string.Format("{0:n0} {1}", Model.Views, _views));
if (Model.Comments > 0)
    items.Add(string.Format("{0:n0} {1}", Model.Comments, _comments));
var result = ", ".Join(items);
```

(Note: all the `@`s make it look like you're writing an ASP.NET MVC view, but I can't quite make sense of how you've placed them, so insert `@`s where necessary.)

Comment: I didn't think about collections. That's really easier and more clean way than ifelse forest. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

- Variables prefixed with @ should generally be avoided - they make the code harder to read.
- The underscore prefix is commonly used for private instance variables. Using it here may be confusing.

For pluralization, check out `System.Data.Entity.Design.PluralizationServices.PluralizationService`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.design.pluralizationservices.pluralizationservice.aspx

Comment: The @ symbol looks like Razor syntax in this example.

Comment: @MattDavey: If they were, they would have been placed at the start of the lines, so I think they are just regular C# `@`s, in which case @Thom Smith's advice makes sense.

Comment: Yeah you're right, it's hard to figure out what's going on with those! It looks like the OP has got confused with Razor syntax and is putting in @ symbols where they're not necessary. On second inspection the code example should function just fine without them.

Comment: Thanx Matt. That what happens. It's razor (I have included a link to an example) and I put them sometimes by mistake..

Thanx for link Thom. I will read it of course in a second.